# how to redirect to the same contact us page after clicking submit

Tags: php, html

I am using single template that is `index.html`. In contact us section after submitting the form "**Thank You, Your message has been sent successfully**" should be shown in the same page and place without reloading to another page. We are using mail-contact.php code as form `action="mail-contact.php" data-ajax="false" method="post" class="form"` in index page.

`mail-contact.php` contains the entire index page code and with some added validation code in contact form, thank you message. So when I click on submit button in contact form it is redirecting to `mail-contact.php` and showing the starting of the page. But I need after clicking submit button it should show thank you message in index page itself.

Comment: In your mail-contact.php. write the code to redirect on the same page with success message.

Comment: Redirect to the same page after submit with some data passed in URL to show success message.

Comment: sir, I do not know any code what to be included. please help me

Comment: In your mail-contact.php somewhere success message is written. after that write header("Location: your page name where you want to send");

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use "flashbag" message.